# Ajax POST Request when Leave the TextBox ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I Need Send to send a POST request , Every-time User leaves the text Box. Need some guidance and calling procedures.

This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getReferenceNo() {
    var postData = { id: "test" }; 
    $.ajax({         
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "xyz/test",
     data: JSON.stringify(postData),
     datatype: "json",
     success: function (result) {
       //do something
       alert("SUCCESS");
      },
     error: function (xmlhttprequest, textstatus, errorthrown) {
         alert("failed");           
     }
  });

}
```

or any other possible way to just send a request to controller. Actual reason is i need to do some background calculation and store the result in the session with a value of view for further use.

Answer (score 1):

use `onblur` with `input` tag as below:

```
<input onblur="getReferenceNo()" type="text" />
```